# Como controlar si una cadena tiene acentos en Python

Tags: python, acentos

Tengo que hacer un código que verifique si una dirección de correo electrónico es valida.
Básicamente esta es la consigna

- Una dirección de correo electrónico consta de dos secciones: la parte local y el dominio, que aparecen antes y después del símbolo @.

Se solicita que, dados una dirección de correo electrónico y un dominio, determinar si dicha dirección es válida.

Podemos decir que una dirección de email es válida si cumple las siguientes características:

Pertenece al dominio ingresado
La parte local no contiene ninguno de los símbolos ()<>@,;:[]ç%&
No debe contener espacios en blanco ni caracteres acentuados
Por ejemplo:

Para la dirección "amelia98@gmail.com" y el dominio "gmail.com", podemos decir que esa dirección es válida.
Para la dirección "MaríaJosé@hotmail.com" y el dominio "hotmail.com", podemos decir que esa dirección es inválida. Puesto que la parte local contiene caracteres acentuados.
Para la dirección "luisSalvatierra@gmail.com" y el dominio "hotmail.com", podemos decir que esa dirección es inválida. Debido a que el dominio ingresado no coincide con el especificado en la dirección de email.
Para la dirección "estevan caliva@gmail.com" y el dominio "gmail.com", podemos decir que esa dirección es inválida. Como podemos ver hay un espacio en blanco en esta dirección de email. Y si bien "caliva@gmail.com" podría ser una dirección válida, toda la dirección debe ser evaluada, no sólo una parte de ella.
Aclaración: suponemos que las direcciones de email ingresadas contienen un único símbolo @.

Y mi solución por el momento era esta, pero no me esta tomando el `.isalnum()` para los acentos.
Busque por todos lados y no encontré alguna solución al respecto.

```
email = str(input("Ingresar el correo --> "))
parts = email.split("@")
check,check2 = False,False
if parts[0].isalnum():
    check = True
    print("part1 correct")
if parts[1] == "gmail.com" or parts[1] == "hotmail.com":
    check2 = True
    print("part2 correct")
if check == True and check2 == True:
    print(f"La direccion {email} es valida.")
else:
    print("La direccion no es valida")
print(parts)
```

Comment: Resumiendo: Necesitas saber como chequear letras con acentos. Toda la explicación de los correos, las direcciones y los emails está de más y sólo dificulta la comprensión de la pregunta, y por ende las respuestas.

Comment: Si, la explicación del email vendría a ser la consigna que me dieron. Si, básicamente quiero chequear si la letra tiene acento o no para dar como invalido el correo electrónico. No me supe explicar bien, disculpas y gracias jaja

Comment: Como profesional debes ir siempre al punto, ser preciso y conciso.

Comment: Desde Python 3.7+ puedes usar [str.isascii()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii), para verificar la no existencia de caracteres extendidos en la cadena. Ej: `'jose_123'.isascii()` -> `True`. `'josé_123'.isascii()` -> `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que realmente quieren que uses son expresiones regulares para comprobar si el email cumple el formato nombre@dominio.algo

Esto es un ejemplo de comprobación de email válido, puedes encontrar mas información [aquí](https://stackabuse.com/python-validate-email-address-with-regular-expressions-regex/):

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+')

def isValid(email):
    if re.fullmatch(regex, email):
      print("Valid email")
    else:
      print("Invalid email")
```